# Rails - Default selected radiobutton in SimpleForm :collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I've litte problem with radiobuttons in SimpleForm.

When i use

```
= f.association :manufactureType, :collection => ManufactureType.all, :as => :radio
```

Rails simply generates few radiobuttons, but none of them are selected.
I want first radiobutton to be selected by default. How can i make it?

Thanks

Comment: Ok. I've found answer for this question. Simply add :checked => 1 (value) at the end of the line and it works :)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you pass in the manufacture types into the view, you can do the following:

```
:checked => @manufacture_types[0]
```

Or

```
:checked => ManufactureType.first
```

Comment: That's gonna reset the button choice if any of the form fields are invalid and it re-renders. I don't know if it's the best way, but I solved this by just setting the the attribute in my `new` action so `@manufacturer = Manufacturer.new (manufacturer_type_id: 0)`

Answer (score 13):

My example was slightly more complicated, none of the other answers worked for me since there was no collection or model to reference.

```
= f.input :attending, as: :radio_buttons, :collection => [ ['Yes', true], ['No', false] ], :checked => ['Yes', true]
```

Answer (score 5):

from op's comment, adding this parameter worked for me:

```
:checked => 1
```

Comment: This worked for me, where the checked answer did not.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an excerpt of my code which works:

```
= f.input :body_format,
  collection: [['markdown', 'Markdown']],
  label_method: :last,
  value_method: :first,
  as: :radio_buttons,
  checked: 'markdown', # THIS
  required: true
```