# rails, simple_form, how to set selected index of a collection when page loaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I am using simple_form gem, I have a countries collection, it work fine when I select the country, and updated record will have the country id stored, but, when I try to edit the record, the chosen country is not selected by default at edit form.

Here is the code at edit form:

```
= f.input :country_id, :collection => all_countries
```

Shouldn't simple_form view the selected country from the db ?

Comment: > Shouldn't simple_form view the selected country from the db ?  
  
It should because simple_form is just a wrapper around rails' form_for helpers. Check your generated html to see if there's no selected option in the code.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if this question didn't use the term "default". When I see that I think that you're talking about what the selected item would be when you have selected nothing before, not when you had stored something and come back to the page.

Comment: yea, I've fixed it, but the question got bit longer :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477942/rails-default-selected-radiobutton-in-simpleform-collection

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Have you tried to use the :selected =>  option?

```
:selected => selected_country_id
```

So,

```
= f.input :country_id, :collection => all_countries, :selected => selected_country_id
```

This will work perfectly !!!

Cheers!

Comment: i.e. `= f.input :country_id, :collection => all_countries, :selected => selected_country_id`

Comment: This does not seem to work when :include_blank is set to true. Might this be a bug?

Comment: The ID was the important part for me. just assigning country, did not work.

Answer (score 16):

I know this has been answered, but I came here looking for a similar solution for a collection of check boxes. For posterity, here's how you do it:

```
<%= f.input :country_ids, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => [['USA', :USA], ['Japan', :JPN]], :checked => [:JPN], :include_hidden => false %>
```

Hope this helps someone.