# simple_form default value with association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, spree

This didn't work me: [Rails - Default selected radiobutton in SimpleForm :collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477942/rails-default-selected-radiobutton-in-simpleform-collection)

I am trying to have a default selection.

I have the following input in my form using simple_form

```
= f.association :collection_page
```

This generates a drop down with all the titles in my CollectionPage object.

Kinda like:

- title1
- title2
- title3

lets say, @collection_page.title = title1

if I do:

```
= f.association :collection_page, as: :radio, :checked => @collection_page.title
```

title1 should be selected by default, but it isn't working for me.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: This post might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107751/rails-simple-form-how-to-set-default-selected-index-of-a-collection

Comment: Kinda seemed like it would work, but not working for me

Comment: You must specify the value of radio button for `checked` key. `id` is the default value for radio buttons. So `checked: @collection_page.id` should work.